# Putting a filled shulker box into another shulker box using a command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I give myself a shulkerbox with another shulkerbox inside it thats filled with items? This is the shulkerbox I want inside the other shulker box:

```
/give @p minecraft:black_shulker_box 1 0  {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:diamond_sword,Slot:0,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:1,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:2,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:3,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:4,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:5,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:6,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:7,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:8,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:9,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:10,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:11,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:12,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:13,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:14,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:14,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:15,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:16,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:17,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:18,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:19,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:20,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:21,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:22,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:23,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:24,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:25,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:26,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:27,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5}}]},display:{Name:"Shadow Guard Sword"}}
```

Comment: I am the one who came up with that original command.  If you are wanting a shulker box filled with stacks of those shulkers then unfortunately Fabian is correct.  Command block limit is 32,767 characters.  The original command alone is 19,640 characters.  You would need roughly that multiplied by 27, plus some more, which would be over 530,280 characters.  Way over the limit.  The stack could be produced by other means but then you risk overflow and crashing your game, I have seen it done before.

Comment: Another thing to point out, since we are talking about length, most of those enchantments on the swords will do nothing.  The only enchants worth having on the sword are 16-21 and replace the enchantment 34 with unbreakable.

Comment: Hey can I get the original code I just want a shucker box within another filled with blocks not the gear hehe

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same you already did for the contents of the inner shulker box, one inside the other. Keep in mind that when a player takes the inner box out of the outer box, he can't put it back in.

`/give @p minecraft:black_shulker_box 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:0,Count:1,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[...]},display:{Name:"Shadow Guard Sword"}}}]}}`

Btw, did you test the command in your question? My answer assumes that that one works.

Also: Do you really think that's enough swords? Just a little hint: Command blocks can contain up to 32768 characters, maybe you could squeeze in a bit more. ;)

Comment: Yes way more words I reduced it to make it easier for you guys to see

Comment: Hey man it has a shucker box inside but how do I put an item inside that one :P

Comment: This is for myself to play with friends and be able to carry stuff to a build site easier :P

Comment: 1. You put the "Items" tag you had where I wrote "Items:{...}". 2. Why carry stuff if you have commands? 3. Don't edit your question to contain the answer! And don't edit your question to ask something different! That destroys the whole Q&A principle!

Answer (score 0):

This command gives a shulker box, filled with stacks of shulker boxes, filled will stacks of stone.  Command is long, 22,116 characters.

```
/give @p minecraft:black_shulker_box 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:0,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:1,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:2,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:3,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:4,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:5,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:6,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:7,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:8,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:9,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:10,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:11,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:12,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:13,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:14,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:15,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:16,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:17,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:18,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:19,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:20,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:21,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:22,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:23,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:24,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:25,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}},{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:26,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}}]}}
```

[image]

I imagine this is just for fun.  If you do the math, this one shulker contains 2,985,984 stone blocks.

If you would like something besides stone, use a text editor with a replace function.  Replace `id:stone` with whichever block you prefer.  Each slot could be a different block if desired.

---

Edit: The requested command.  A shulker with a single stack of shulkers inside it which are filled with stone.

```
/give @p minecraft:black_shulker_box 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:0,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}}]}}
```

Comment: Is this debugged its not working for some reason says parsing failed

Comment: Nvm I got it to work :P

Comment: Hey is it possible to get that again to spawn in another shucker box but only the first slot so its stacked?

Comment: I just realized you changed your question very drastically to the point that my answer no longer seems to answer your question or even belong here.  It also seems you are asking separate question in the comments.  Editing your question is available so you can clarify your question and fix errors.  It should not be used to change the question entirely.  If you have another question, ask another question.

Comment: Wow. Impossible on console edition...