# (Bigger Question) Explanation and Questions for KitPVP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

Ok, I'm trying again with the Kit PVP questions. Here's an explanation of what I'm trying to do: My friend and I have our own server. The main part that we're working on right now is the KitPVP section. We have I think 10 or 11 kits so far. You start out with two which are Brute and Stinky. The others are locked. We already have the maps under control but the main part we need is a way to get the actual kits. I already made it so when you kill another player you get an emerald and we have an emerald storage system. I was thinking that in the KitPVP lobby, there would be a villager which is modded to sell the keys to the locked shulker boxes (which have the kits in them). I also need them to refill after someone takes the kits out of there. Basically, I need a way to make it so when they take the kit out, they can't take another kit unless they want to replace it, but then I also need a way so the shulker box automatically refills after they take the kit out of it.

Comment: You haven't actually showed us anything you've tried at all.  All you've done is explain a little about what it is you're *trying* to do.  Show us some commands!  Some research!  Just about anything that shows you've made an attempt yourself.  There's plenty you can do, but it does take effort.

Comment: No, all you've done is told us what you're trying to do.  Where are you showing what you've tried?  All I see is that you have some replaceitem commands, but you don't even show those.  If you have tried, then, please, show us the commands, what they do, and why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: *Sigh* ok, I'm just not very good at coming up with commands myself

Comment: We can, but we like to see you put some effort in, first.  Do some research, try some commands.  You have Google, just like the rest of us.  See if you can find something that might work, and alter it.  See what it does.  **Then** come to us, if it doesn't work, show us the command, and tell us why it doesn't work.  We dislike being used as a command on demand service.

Comment: I usually need help with that kind of stuff, but all my friends know like absolutely nothing about commands. I know a lot but just not enough to come up with them

Comment: Ok, I'll work on that for a little and get back to you

Comment: So far so good.

Comment: I got some locked shulker boxes in there and got seperate keys for them all

Comment: What are in the kits?  Instead of trying to refill kits and prevent a user from taking more then one, why not just use the give command.  You could give the user a filled shulker box (locked if you want it to be).  The shulker box could be the kit.  Or you could give the items directly to the user.  If you want to see an extreme case of prefilled shulkers, [here is an answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/315973/186522) I gave about having prefilled shulker boxes inside shulker boxes.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this site: https://www.digminecraft.com/generators/villager_trade.php It has helped me with costume villager trades and more. As for the kits I would say no kits. Make it so the player gets starter gear and let them battle it out and when they get kills let them trade with the villager to get better armor, weapons, etc. I hope you found this helpful =)

Comment: Just pointing someone at another site doesn't really answer the question.  Please try to directly answer the question, in your answer.

Comment: Thanks normal guy but that's kinda how KitPVP works. We need kits